# Assert called with argument of specific type

Tags: python, mocking

I want to check in my test if a function is called with an argument of a specific class.

```
class Foo:
...
```

I found mock.ANY, but there I cannot pass any class. What is want is:

```
test_mock.assert_called_with("expected string", ANY(spec=Foo))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved it with a custom matcher.

```
class TypeMatcher:

def __init__(self, expected_type):
    self.expected_type = expected_type

def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, self.expected_type)
```

And then test it like this:

```
test_mock.assert_called_with("expected string", TypeMatcher(Foo))
```

Comment: I got an assertion error that the expected string was not a `TypeMatcher`

Answer (score 5):

Use a different test. The `call_args` attribute contains the arguments passed to the call; you can extract the desired argument, then check its type.

```
# E.g. test_mock(1,"foo", bar=9) gives 
# test_mock.call_args == ((1, "foo"), {"bar": 9})
assert isinstance(test_mock.call_args[1][1], Foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check by the name of the class by using the class name:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

a = MyClass(3)
print(a.__class__.__name__)
if a.__class__.__name__ == "MyClass":
    ...
```